# FHIR one actor in two different roles

Tags: function, roles, actor, hl7-fhir, hapi

I'm creating a procedure in a transaction bundle and add practitioners as actors to the performers collection, having different functions. As far as the practitioners references are unique, all is fine. But when I'm trying to add a practitioners twice, with a different functions, an exception is thrown:

```
Can not process entity with ID[urn:uuid:7165d406-da59-4436-aa93-372ca882c4e5], this is not a valid FHIR ID
```

I found this message in HAPI FHIR unit tests, but in my case, the uuid seems to be fine. But maybe only one uuid is replaced with the id of the created practitioner.

I'm also not sure, whether this is the correct way for what I want to achieve.

I also tried to add the practioner only once and then add the second role to function.coding. But the resulting entry looks for me kinda strange:

```
performer": [
          {
            "function": {
              "coding": [
                {
                  "system": "http://somewhere/performer-role",
                  "code": "88888888"
                },
                {
                  "system": "http://somewhere/performer-role",
                  "code": "99999999",
                  "display": "Role-2"
                }
              ],
              "text": "Role-1"
            },
            "actor": {
              "reference": "Practitioner/2925"
            }
          },
```

I'm fairly new to Fhir. Does anybody knows what's wrong here ?
And, what's the recommended practice, to have one performer/actor in to different roles ?

Thanks in advance

P.S. I'm using HAPI FHIR 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Multiple coding repetitions would be used to convey translations - so you're saying that 888888888 and 99999999 are two different codes that represent the same role.  If you want to indicate that the same Practitioner had two different roles, then you need to have two different performer repetitions.  E.g.

```
perfomer: [
    {
        "function": {
            "coding": [ {
                "system": "http://somewhere/performer-role",
                "code": "88888888"
            }]},
        "actor": {
          "reference": "Practitioner/2925"
        }
    }, {
        "function": {
            "coding": [ {
                "system": "http://somewhere/performer-role",
                "code": "99999999"
            }]},
        "actor": {
          "reference": "Practitioner/2925"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Lloyd. Yes, that's what I aim at. But as I described, adding another performer referring to the same practitioner leads to the exception shown above.

Comment: Does that UUID appear anywhere in your instance?